# Can class with const members be assigned or copied

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, member, move-constructor

According to abseil.io/tips/177, it said

> Specifically, if your class has const members, it cannot be assigned to (whether by copy-assignment or move-assignment). The language understands this: if your type has a const member, copy-assignment and move-assignment operators will not be synthesized.

I created a short snippet, I saw objects can be copied/moved. How could I understand that statement from abseil.io/tips/177?

```
#include <iostream>
class Stitch {
 public:
  Stitch(int in):num(in) { std::cout << "c'tor, address:" << this << std::endl; }
  ~Stitch() { std::cout << "d'tor, address:" << this << std::endl; }
  const int num;
  const std::size_t kAddr = (int)(this);
};
int main() {
  Stitch s1(1);
  std::cout << "s1 address: " << &s1 << " " << s1.num << std::endl;
  Stitch s2 = s1;
  std::cout << "s2 address: " << &s2 << " " << s2.num <<  std::endl;
  Stitch s3 = std::move(s1);
  std::cout << "s3 address: " << &s3 << " " << s3.num <<  std::endl;
  Stitch s4 = Stitch(4);
  std::cout << "s4 address: " << &s4 << " " << s4.num <<  std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `Stitch s2 = s1;` is not assignment. In c++, initialization and assignment are different things. For example, `s2 = s1;` is assignment. The quote talks about assignment not initialization.

Comment: The object is not const during construction plus the statement talks about assignment and not initialization.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I understand that statement

The statement talks about **assignment** and not **initialization**. They are different things. In particular, `Stitch s2 = s1;` is **copy initialization** and not *copy assignment*. So since `Stitch s2 = s1;` is copy initialization, the copy *constructor* can be used.

The important thing to here is that, **the object is not const during construction otherwise the constructor won't be able to initialize the object as all of its data member would be const.**

On the other hand, `s2 = s1;` is copy assignment which is what the quoted statement talks about.

Comment: What is meant by: **the object is not const during construction** ?